# Are ALL values between the average value +- the variance?

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, random, standard-deviation, variance

I heard that 68,268% of the random values are in the range between the average value ± σ, 95,449% of the values are in the range between the average value ± 2*σ...

Are **always all** values in the range between the average ± σ^2 (average ± the variance) or is it "almost" 100% of them?

Comment: No, it’s never all the values. For the proper inequality, look at chebychev inequality

Comment: A RV with normal distribution has finite variance, yet takes arbitrarily high values with non-zero probability.